# How to pass list from one activity to other activity and all the time mantain same instance?

Tags: android, android-activity

I don't know how to solve my problems. It goes like this:

In main activtiy I make my own objects and added them to list(arrayList) and after that when I go to another activity I would like to:

1. to send list of list og my own ojbects, I know you make it with: intent.putExtra but you don't have type list myObject
2. when I pass the list of lists of objects I think it makes new istance of these datas, but I would like to have one istance all the tame and I would like them to read and manipulate on first instance.

More explanation in my main activity I make objects and they are ready for all other activityes and all other activitys can read and write my list od lists. Only one activity is active in a time.

And I am also intetrested in when I manupilated the data in some activity and I would like to go to main menu and pick other activity how to send from that first activity to menu activity and pass them to next activity to process.

Would you help me, please. Best regards Robert

Comment: Befroe I return to main activtiy in my currently activity I make:                            finish();
System.exit(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you implement an [application object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), and have the objects that you're referring to live in the application object rather than an activity object.  There can be only application object associated with any particular app, and it gets created before any Activity objects, and is independent of whatever activity objects are created/destroyed during the lifetime of your app.  Hence you don't need to worry about sharing your objects between activities, because they're all available globally in the application object.

Comment: I agree with the above answer.